# How to check thread memory usage in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory

I am debugging application, and I am investigating a memory usage in it. The app is multithreaded and I want to check how much memory each of thread is using. How is it possible to do, cause in standard columns I did not find any of memory column?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: *I want to check how much memory each of thread is using.* Do you mean their stacks, or TLS? Heap memory is mutualized between threads.

Comment: Heap memory may well be available to all threads, but it seems clear to me that the person asking the question wants to know how much heap memory each thread uses. That is the obvious interpretation of the question to me. And there is a tool to do it. C++ Memory Validator can give you the stats on the above and not just for the C/C++ heap.

Answer (score 1):

The process owns the memory, not the thread, so a whilst a thread have an overhead for its stack, etc. that tends to be fixed per thread, with any dynamically allocated memory belonging to the process, able to be read/written by any thread.